# Hits counter not displaying the counter

Tags: php

I followed this example i found online, but it is not working

http://hibbard.eu/how-to-make-a-simple-visitor-counter-using-php/
co counter displays, it does create the counter.txt file
i am testing t on localhost in chrome

herewith my code:

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Login Form</title>
 </head>
 <body background="images/stockvault.jpg">      
    <b><ul>THIS IS A WORK IN PROGRESS</ul></b>
    <br />  
    <br />    
    <img alt="hit counter" src="php/counter.php" />
    <br />  
    <br />      
 </body>
 </html>
```

then my php file:

```
  <?php
  session_start();
  $counter_name = "counter.txt";

 // Check if a text file exists. If not create one and initialize it to zero.
 if (!file_exists($counter_name)) {
   $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
   fwrite($f,"0");
   fclose($f);
 }


 // Read the current value of our counter file
 $f = fopen($counter_name,"r");
 $counterVal = fread($f, filesize($counter_name));
 fclose($f);

// Has visitor been counted in this session?
// If not, increase counter value by one
 if(!isset($_SESSION['hasVisited'])){
    $_SESSION['hasVisited']="yes";
    $counterVal++;
    $f = fopen($counter_name, "w");
    fwrite($f, $counterVal);
    fclose($f); 
  }


  $counterVal = str_pad($counterVal, 5, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
  $chars = preg_split('//', $counterVal);

   // Change directory
   chdir("../");

  // Get current directory
  //echo getcwd();
  chdir("images");


  $im = imagecreatefrompng("images.png");
  $src1 = imagecreatefrompng("$chars[1].png");
  $src2 = imagecreatefrompng("$chars[2].png");
  $src3 = imagecreatefrompng("$chars[3].png");
  $src4 = imagecreatefrompng("$chars[4].png");
  $src5 = imagecreatefrompng("$chars[5].png");

  imagecopymerge($im, $src1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 56, 75, 100);
  imagecopymerge($im, $src2, 60, 0, 0, 0, 56, 75, 100);
  imagecopymerge($im, $src3, 120, 0, 0, 0, 56, 75, 100);
  imagecopymerge($im, $src4, 180, 0, 0, 0, 56, 75, 100);
  imagecopymerge($im, $src5, 240, 0, 0, 0, 56, 75, 100);

  header('Content-Type: image/png');
  echo (imagepng($im));
  imagedestroy($im);
 ?>
```

output is:

[image]

Comment: Is the path to images correct?

Comment: yes i checked it with echo getcwd();

Comment: What is the current output that you are getting?

Comment: the html code is my page2.html which has the "call" to  counter.php please see OP

Comment: Look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php). What does it return? A boolean. You're outputting the image contents followed by a `1` (`true`, the response of `imagepng` converted to a string). Change `echo (imagepng($im))` to `imagepng($im)`. When someone asked about the output, then open up your PHP file in the browser and see if you have any errors.

Comment: There's a problem in the path/name of your images.

Comment: i have tried localhost/php/counter.php and again just the small "no image" icon thingy displays

Comment: I don't know if you solved your issue, but you need to look at the _source_ of `counter.php` (on chrome simply append `view-source:` to your URL) to see if any errors show up. Either that or use another content-type (eg. `text/plain`) while testing responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot this part of the code in the beginning of your PHP code, at least in your copy&paste.

```
session_start();
$counter_name = "counter.txt";
```

You need the session_start() to handle $_SESSION variables, and asign the generated file counter.txt to $counter_name

Comment: oops yes i have that in my code, will add it here too, sorry

Comment: Are your imagenes in .png? Are you sure the image's name are correct? Did you check the output with firebug?

Comment: yes it is a png, i used paint to create .png and i have chome's developer tools open which is similar to firebug yes the name is correct, checked it :)